# Problem with Aligning Equations in a Table

Tags: tables, align

I am still relatively new to LaTeX, and are trying to create a table for a set of solutions.

The basic code I have at the moment is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding,enumitem}
\usepackage{ifetex}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\checked}[2][0.5cm]{%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright\ding{51}}\parbox[t]{\linewidth-#1}{#2}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7.3cm}|p{7.3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|}
\hline

\textbf{Solutions} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Specific Behaviours}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Point}}\\
\hline

If $z_1=3-2i$ is a root of $p(z)$ then $(z-3+2i)$ and $(z-3-2i)$ are factors. Likewise $p(-2)=0 \Rightarrow (z+2)$ is a factor.\\
$\begin{aligned}
    p(z)&=(z-3+2i)(z-3-2i)(z+2)\\
        &=(z^2-6z+13)(z+2)\\
        &=z^3+2z^2-6z^2-12z+13z+26\\
        &=z^3-4z^2+z+26
\end{aligned}$
&
\checked{Substitutes and expands.}
&
3.1.1 3.1.2 3.1.3\\

\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

However when I typeset the code, the table it produces is not what I want or expect.

[image]

For some reason the text in the second column aligns in the middle of the equation, and the three numbers in the last column align with the top of this text. Also the vertical border on the far right hand column seems to start with the `\begin{aligned}` command.

Ideally I would like the text in the second and third column to be aligned to the top of the column.

Comment: Okay, I think it has something to do with the `\\` in the table forcing it to start a new row. If that is correct, how does one insert a line break in a table?

Comment: Just replace the double-backslash after "is a factor." with an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

Since you load `tabularx` package, I would exploit it in your table. Beside this I would add `makecell` package for adding some small vertical spaces in cells and use its `\thead` command for column headers:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}       % <---
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}   % <---
\renewcommand\theadgape{}                       % <---
\setcellgapes{3pt}                              % <---

\newcommand{\checked}[2][0.5cm]{%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright\ding{51}}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X
                             |>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
                             |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{11mm}|}
    \hline
\thead{Solutions} & \thead{Specific Behaviours} & \thead{Point} \\
    \hline
If $z_1=3-2i$ is a root of $p(z)$ then $(z-3+2i)$ and $(z-3-2i)$ are factors. Likewise $p(-2)=0 \Rightarrow (z+2)$ is a factor.

\medskip
$\begin{aligned}
    p(z)&=(z-3+2i)(z-3-2i)(z+2)\\
        &=(z^2-6z+13)(z+2)\\
        &=z^3+2z^2-6z^2-12z+13z+26\\
        &=z^3-4z^2+z+26
\end{aligned}$
    &   \checked{Substitutes and expands.}
        &   3.1.1 3.1.2 3.1.3\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

or like this?

[image]

In above table I consider that your table body has two rows as can be concluded from your MWE. In it in the first row of table body are missed two ampersands, hence there are missed vertical lines in the last two cells in the row.

For align text in the second and third column with top of equation you need add `[t]` position specifier to `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}       % <---
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}   % <---
\renewcommand\theadgape{}                       % <---
\setcellgapes{3pt}                              % <---

\newcommand{\checked}[2][0.5cm]{%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright\ding{51}}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X
                             |>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
                             |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{11mm}|}
    \hline
\thead{Solutions} & \thead{Specific Behaviours} & \thead{Point} \\
    \hline
If $z_1=3-2i$ is a root of $p(z)$ then $(z-3+2i)$ and $(z-3-2i)$ are factors. Likewise $p(-2)=0 \Rightarrow (z+2)$ is a factor. 
    &   &   \\          % <---
 $\begin{aligned}[t]    % <---
    p(z)&=(z-3+2i)(z-3-2i)(z+2)\\
        &=(z^2-6z+13)(z+2)\\
        &=z^3+2z^2-6z^2-12z+13z+26\\
        &=z^3-4z^2+z+26
\end{aligned}$
    &   \checked{Substitutes and expands.}
        &   3.1.1 3.1.2 3.1.3\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the equation in a minipage, it works.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\checked}[2][0.5cm]{%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright\ding{51}}\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-#1}{#2}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7.3cm}|p{7.3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|}
\hline

\textbf{Solutions} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Specific Behaviours}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Point}}\\
\hline
\begin{minipage}{7.3cm}
\centering
If $z_1=3-2i$ is a root of $p(z)$ then $(z-3+2i)$ and $(z-3-2i)$ are factors.
Likewise $p(-2)=0 \Rightarrow (z+2)$ is a factor.\\
$\begin{aligned}
    p(z)&=(z-3+2i)(z-3-2i)(z+2)\\
        &=(z^2-6z+13)(z+2)\\
        &=z^3+2z^2-6z^2-12z+13z+26\\
        &=z^3-4z^2+z+26
\end{aligned}$
\end{minipage}
&
\checked{Substitutes and expands.}
&
3.1.1 3.1.2 3.1.3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or not this is pretty is another question. (I also changed the `\checked` command.)

Answer (score 0):

The `\arraybackslash` directive should be given only for the *last* column, if you plan to use `\\` in the previous ones.

Indeed, you get the expected output if you remove it from the first column specification: its effect is to make `\\` behave as “end the table row here”, which is not what you want.

Here's a slightly different realization, where you don't need to guess the column widths.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding,enumitem}
\usepackage{ifetex}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\checked}[2][0.5cm]{%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright\ding{51}}\parbox[t]{\linewidth-#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\column}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|X|c|}
\hline

\textbf{Solutions} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Specific Behaviours}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Point}}\\
\hline

If $z_1=3-2i$ is a root of $p(z)$ then $(z-3+2i)$ and $(z-3-2i)$ are factors. 
Likewise $p(-2)=0 \Rightarrow (z+2)$ is a factor.

\centering
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    p(z)&=(z-3+2i)(z-3-2i)(z+2)\\
        &=(z^2-6z+13)(z+2)\\
        &=z^3+2z^2-6z^2-12z+13z+26\\
        &=z^3-4z^2+z+26
\end{aligned}$
&
\checked{Substitutes and expands.}
&
\column{3.1.1 \\ 3.1.2 \\ 3.1.3} \\

\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left all packages, but I don't think you need all of them, in particular `ifetex`, nor `mwe`.